# Inline form MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a inline form using the bootstrap template of MVC, but when i create an inline form with this code:

```
<form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
    </form>
```

this is the result:

[image]

how can achieve a inline form?

Comment: It is because of the labels. Define some custom CSS to move button down.

Comment: also with only one label and one input, the input is alway on another line, can you give me an example?

Comment: I believe you have some additional styles which override labels. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

Comment: I'm using the Bootstrap v3.0.0, I haven't make any changes, just as is, can't be a limit of MVC?

Comment: Can you upgrade to the most recent version (v3.3.7)? The inline form on latest version does exactly what you need

Comment: have you tried putting the button within its own `form-group` div as well?

Comment: Upgrading, as suggested by @Morpheus worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add your button in form group

```
<div class="form-group">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="col-lg-4" id="userFormColumn1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" id="userFormColumn1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" id="userFormColumn1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Try this.